# prove that $|\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}|\leq |\mathbb{R}|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

prove that $|\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}|\leq |\mathbb{R}|$

Could you give me a suggestion to create a correspondence?

Let $f:\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow {\mathbb{R}}$

I must prove that f is injective but I don't know what correspondence I could use. Any suggestion?

Comment: You can use $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty 3^{-k}x(k)$.

Comment: $f\to 0.f(0)f(1)f(2)f(3)...$

Comment: @Gae.S. That $x$ would be a sequence that is in $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: Seeing what the domain of $f$ is, $x$ would be an element of $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$, yes.

Comment: @Gae.S. So when proving that $x(k)=y(k)$, can I conclude that $x = y$?

Comment: It is true that $x=y$ if and only if, for all $k\in\Bbb N$, $x(k)=y(k)$.

Comment: @Gae.S. I get it. One last doubt. Could you tell me by take that correspondence?

Comment: "Let $f\colon\{0,1\}^\Bbb N\to\Bbb R$ be $f(x)=0$, then $f$ is not injective. When you say "let ..." you are taking an arbitrary object satisfying your assumptions (which may or may not define a unique object, or be impossible to satisfy (e.g. "let $x$ be a natural number such that $x+1=0$")), so unless you specify *what* is $f$, you cannot prove it is injective, since there are such functions $f$ which are not injective.